# Sum the values of the array with a method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

So I'm trying to get 10 inputs from a user via Console, store in them in an array, calculate in a method what the sum is and return it. I'm still in the process, so this isn't mean to be completed code, but I'm confused at this point why my error list says Main should be closed after the while statement?

```
    class Program
{//Start class

    //We need to declare the size of our array
    const int ARRAYSIZE = 10;


    static void Main()
    {//Start main

        //We need to create a counter for how many entries we currently have
        int entries = 0;
        int sumScore = 0;

        //We need to create the array 
        int[] myArray = new int[ARRAYSIZE];

        //Start a loop to ask for input
        do
        {//Start loop
            Console.Write("Please enter the score of each test: ");
            int entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            myArray[entries] = entry;
            entries++;

            }
            while (entries < ARRAYSIZE);//End loop

           static void PrintArray(int[ ] myArray)
            {
                foreach(int value in myArray)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
                Console.ReadLine();
             }
           }
    }//End main
}//End class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced the closing bracket of your Main method. You may also want to call your PrintArray method after `while (entries < ARRAYSIZE);//End loop`and also compute your sum inside that method. But I guess it is because, as you said, it is a work in progress. Here is what it looks like

```
 class Program
{
    const int ARRAYSIZE = 10;

    static void Main()
    {//Start main

        //We need to create a counter for how many entries we currently have
        int entries = 0;
        int sumScore = 0;

        //We need to create the array 
        int[] myArray = new int[ARRAYSIZE];

        //Start a loop to ask for input
        do
        {//Start loop
            Console.Write("Please enter the score of each test: ");
            int entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            myArray[entries] = entry;
            entries++;

        }
        while (entries < ARRAYSIZE);//End loop
        PrintArray(myArray);

      }//End main

      static void PrintArray(int[ ] myArray)
      {
            int sum = 0;
            foreach(int value in myArray)
            {
                 sum += value;
                 Console.WriteLine(value);
                 Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
       }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the position of `static void PrintArray(int[ ] myArray)`, you are declaring a new function.  You need the `}//End main` before you declare a new function:

```
   do
    {//Start loop
        Console.Write("Please enter the score of each test: ");
        int entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        myArray[entries] = entry;
        entries++;

        }
        while (entries < ARRAYSIZE);//End loop
}//End main
       static void PrintArray(int[ ] myArray)
        {
            foreach(int value in myArray)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.ReadLine();
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I thought it might be interesting for you.

If you'd like to do this in a slightly easier way, then try this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var sum =
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, ARRAYSIZE)
            .Select(n =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the score of each test:");
                return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            })
            .Sum();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("The sum is:");
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```